# React Native - how to enter number only in a textbox (I need + character included)

Tags: react-native, node-modules

I tried `keyboardType='number-pad'` and `keyboardType='numeric'` i get a keyboard without the character +

I want the user to enter the Phone Number with the country Code (i.e)  '+' sign is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the keyboard type:

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#keyboardtype

You need to set the keyboardType to be a a 'phone-pad'

```
<TextInput keyboardType={'phone-pad'} />
```